# Options for localization of gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, localization, add-on

I want to publish a gmail addon and i wonder what are the possibilities of localization. I want the addon to be usable in 3 different languages.

I thought there would be a mention of it [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publish-add-on-overview) but i couldn't find it.

Comment: I don't believe that this question is a duplicate of the one that its marked as. In any case, it is possible, see [this article](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/create-listing) it mentions that you should create localized **versions** and when you make your listing, you can define them there.

Comment: Just to clarify does it allow to submit several version of the addon each translated to different language or is is just for the description text in the store?

Comment: I was wrong, its not referring to versions of your app, only the description of it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer

To localize your add-on you need to do two things.

1. **Modify your script to adapt its UI** - [Access the user locale](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/access-user-locale)  or [`getActiveUserLocale()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUserLocale()) are the key methods. Use these within the Add-on, and use that to change the interface accordingly. For example:

```js
if (userLocale == "en") {
  // Render English UI
} else if (userLocale == "es") {
  // Render Spanish UI
}
```

2. When you are creating your [listing](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/create-listing) in Google Cloud Platform. Ensure you add in different versions of the **title and descriptions** so that these appear in the right locales. This is only for the Marketplace listing.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer i think that this will be the final one i just have one issue that i described in the edit in my original question.

Comment: No problem, but your edit to the question is **out of scope of the original question** its like adding in another question to an old one and it is very different to the main one. You should open another question as detailed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) - sorry not to be able to help you further.